# GWT and EasyMock - can't call createStrictMock()

Tags: java, gwt, junit, easymock

I'm trying to use EasyMock to facilitate testing my GWT project but I get an error on the `createStrictMock` method:

```
import com.BiddingSystem.client.Presenter.CreateTopicPresenter;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager;
import org.easymock.*;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import com.google.gwt.junit.GWTMockUtilities;

public class TestBiddingSystem extends TestCase
{
    private CreateTopicPresenter TopicPresenter;
    private BiddingSysAsync MockRPC;
    private HandlerManager EventBus;
    private CreateTopicPresenter.Display TopicDisplay

    protected void setUpd()
    {
        EventBus = new HandlerManager(null);
        TopicDisplay = createStrictMock.(createTopicPresenter.Display.class);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post code as text, not screenshots.

Comment: Next time I may not be around, so here are the instructions: 1) copy the code from your text editor (Ctrl+C) 2) paste it into your browser (Ctrl+V) 3) select it and press the code formatting button `{}`. There.

Answer (score 3):

The `createStrictMock` method can't be found. Add the following import to the class:

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;
```